# Laravel Cashier not completing code execution after successful payment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cashier

I am using laravel cashier to handle multiple subscription for a user. Everytime a user wants to create a new `Product` he/she has to subscribe. here is the code that I am using on the backend:

```
$user = Auth::user();

    // Charge user and create a new subscription
    try {
        $subscription = $user->newSubscription('default', env('STRIPE_PRICE_ID'))->create();
    } catch (IncompletePayment $exception) {
        return redirect()->route(
            'cashier.payment',
            [$exception->payment->id, 'redirect' => route('dashboard')]
        );
    }

    // Create a new prod for the user
    $prod = new Product([
        'title' => $this->title,
        'icon_url' => $this->icon_url,
    ]);
    $prod->user()->associate($user);
    $prod->save();
```

Here user is redirected to a /payment page where he/she enters necessary details, completes payment and once charged successfully, a popup notifies them of the same, but the user is never redirected back to dashboard, nor does the follow up code executes. I definitely missed something crucial, can you guys please let me know where was I wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When the new subscription fails you are redirecting the user to a different page:

```php
return redirect()->route(...);
```

The code after the `return` will never be executed. In this case, creating the product.

In the docs you will find:

> After confirming their payment, the user will be redirected to the URL provided by the redirect parameter specified above. Upon redirection, message (string) and success (integer) query string variables will be added to the URL.

So the creation of the Product may need to be moved to a different endpoint.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/billing#handling-failed-payments

Comment: I think that applies to the case where the payment fails, my question is for when the payment completes successfully and the person hits on the "Go Back" button in the success window that appears.